# how to display an excel spreadsheet on browser using jsps.?

Tags: excel, jsp, servlets, apache-poi, jxl

i had a excel sheet which is coming to a jsp from the servlet. Can someone help me of how to write a jsp page to display the excel contents in the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to rebuild MS Excel in Java?

Answer (score 0):

If the excel is not changing the structure dynamically, I recommend you to build a set of objects and parse these information in the server, and then in the jsp read these objects to build an html table with this set of objects.

You can load an Excel file with the class HSSFWorkbook or XSSFWorkbook, and then loop to the rows and cells for building your objects.

Please have a look at the examples of Apache Poi [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

You can do something like this...

> ```
>      if(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {
>             lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
>             for(int j = 0; j <= lastRowNum; j++) {
>                 row = sheet.getRow(j);
>                 lastCellNum = row.getLastCellNum();
>         for(int i = 0; i <= lastCellNum; i++) {
>             cell = row.getCell(i);
>             if(cell == null) {
>                 csvLine.add("");
>             }
>             else { //set your properties here...
>             }
>         }
>             }
>         }
> ```